# Whenever I create a new project in Unity in Windows, I get the following errors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I create a new project in Unity, I get the following 4 errors:

> 1. Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 2.9.1.65535 (9d34608e) Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> error CS2012: Cannot open 'C:\Users\Marius\Documents\New Unity Project
>   (3)\Temp\Unity.Analytics.DataPrivacy.dll' for writing -- 'Access to
>   the path 'C:\Users\Marius\Documents\New Unity Project
>   (3)\Temp\Unity.Analytics.DataPrivacy.dll' is denied.'
>
> 2. error CS2012: Cannot open 'C:\Users\Marius\Documents\New Unity Project (3)\Temp\Unity.CollabProxy.Editor.dll' for writing -- 'Access
>      to the path 'C:\Users\Marius\Documents\New Unity Project
>      (3)\Temp\Unity.CollabProxy.Editor.dll' is denied.'
> 3. error CS2012: Cannot open 'C:\Users\Marius\Documents\New Unity Project (3)\Temp\Unity.PackageManagerUI.Editor.dll' for writing --
>      'Access to the path 'C:\Users\Marius\Documents\New Unity Project
>      (3)\Temp\Unity.PackageManagerUI.Editor.dll' is denied.'
> 4. error CS2012: Cannot open 'C:\Users\Marius\Documents\New Unity Project (3)\Temp\Unity.TextMeshPro.dll' for writing -- 'Access to the
>      path 'C:\Users\Marius\Documents\New Unity Project
>      (3)\Temp\Unity.TextMeshPro.dll' is denied.'

I am pretty new to Unity and C#. Even if I go ahead and complete the tutorial ball game, I got an error saying "All compiler errors have to be fixed before you can enter playmode!". I tried reinstalling both Unity and Visual Studio 2017 but the errors keep on coming. Could anyone tell me where the error is coming from?

Comment: does it happen with other project types?

Comment: Have you tried running VS as admin or giving yourself permissions on these folders?

Comment: @DanielA.White other project types in Visual Studio? No, I haven't.

Comment: I ran it as an admin but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a read permissions issue. Make sure you are logged in as an admin, or try to start a project in a public folder.

Comment: I saved the project in a public folder and it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The DataPrivacy error is easily solved, click  window at the top of the unity editor. then click on Package Manager, then find Analytics Library and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I signed off and signed back into Unity, and is gone, seems to be a permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

see the link [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/307464/cs2012-cannot-open-an-executable-for-writing.html)

See the comment 2 of Andy Gocke [MSFT]  "The most common reason for intermittent file locks is an over-aggressive antivirus scanner." and check your installed antivirus.